# Development team budget for training and social activities

Tags: project-team, team-building, budget

I am trying to understand if our team budget is aligned with the outside world,

This is the closest sub forum out there...

 For a big company (500+ employees)

 What is the budget for 5-10 developers for social activities and educational activities 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to ignore internal on the job training, mentoring, etc.

Training budgets are important; it's allows for your employees to be better equipped to do their job, and gives the employer more bang for the buck - in that with proper training you can get junior developers up to more senior levels of expertise. General expenses include;

- Monthly subscriptions to online training like pluralsite; $100/month/dev
- Quartlery Conferances; $1000/quarter/dev
- Serious training and certicatation courses: $2500/year/dev

Activities are important not just for moral, but breaking out of the day to day grind that can become a burden to both managers and staff;

- Quarterly team building; $200/quarter/month/dev
- Weekly drinks, coffeess, lunches etc; $200/week/per team

Things to keep in mind is that in the budgeting world this is part of the overall employment package - I've had to work with budgets where the previous manager had used the entire budget for salaries - getting more budget was hard.

And although I am all for higher salaries, having a good work culture, and ongoing training is important. Make sure your team is aware at how their entire employment package is structured, point out the impact of training on their careers. Sometimes it's a salary/benefits balance and this needs to be comminicated.